# SVN - Checked out copy cannot be committed: 'not a working copy'

Tags: svn, version-control, commit, visualsvn-server

I've just set up VisualSVN Server and slik SVN clients.

I imported a project from my desktop computer into the repository. Then, on my laptop I checked out a copy and made some changes. When I tried to commit, it failed saying it was not a working copy.

I thought maybe I had somehow messed up the svn files, not sure how I would have though. Anyway, I checked out another copy and then immediately tried to commit it, but again, it said not a working copy.

I must be missing something here.

**edit**

I used svn import to import the project
and svn checkout to checkout the project

Comment: Do you get output when running svn log or svnversion commands in your checked out project?

Comment: Are you sure you did the `svn commit` from *inside* the checked-out directory? `svn co file:///dir/repos/project; cd project; change-stuff; svn ci -m "changed stuff"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you check out, it might have created an extra sub-folder, e.g., `MyProject\MyProject`. In this case, the working folder would actually be the lower directory. If you try to commit from the higher directory, it will say it is not a working copy (because it isn't, you need to go one level down).